# How to detect compatibility errors - SQL Server 2012 

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, compatibility-level

I am changing a database's compatibility mode from 90 (SQL Server 2005) to 110 (SQL 2012) and I am wondering at what point would I see errors from breaking changes if there are any.

I ran Upgrade Advisor 2012 which spotted several Stored Procedures that needed updating. An  example was:

"In SQL Server 2005 or later, column aliases in the ORDER BY clause cannot be prefixed by the table alias."

However, when I run this stored procedure in SQL 2012 (without having made changes) it doesn't show any errors. Also, when I changed the database compatibility level from 90 to 110 there were also no errors. Nor when I restored the database.

If I am not seeing errors anywhere, I am hoping that Upgrade Advisor caught everything. Is there any other ways I should check for compatibility errors?

Also, how is it possible that this stored procedure ran successfully even though Upgrade Advisor told me it would fail? Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you show the query? Just because it runs doesn't mean it's correct. :-) For example this is not legal, but it works:

```
SELECT CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, modify_date) AS modify_date
FROM sys.objects AS o
ORDER BY o.modify_date;
```

Technically, it should be as follows, since `o.modify_date` is not in the `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, modify_date) AS modify_date
FROM sys.objects AS o
ORDER BY modify_date;
```

In [this Connect bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/546782/sql-server-upgrade-advisor-column-aliases-in-order-by-clause-cannot-be-prefixed-by-table-alias), it was stated that this rule would be removed from the Upgrade Advisor. I suspect that one of the following (or both) happened:

1. They forgot to remove the rule as they said they would
2. They had other complications which prevented the above syntax from being blocked by the parser

---

That all said, there are some breaking changes the upgrade advisor will never catch. For example, this will work on 2005, 2008 and 2008 R2:

```
CREATE TABLE #foo(id INT);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#foo') > 0
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE #foo;
END
GO

CREATE TABLE #foo(id INT);
```

This will break in SQL Server 2012, however, since #temp tables now get a negative object_id. The proper way to test is:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#foo') IS NOT NULL
```

[I go over a few other issues in this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/06/27/sql-server-v-next-denali-why-you-should-start-testing-early). A couple of other breaking changes:

- https://sqlblog.org/2011/06/28/sql-server-v-next-denali-breaking-change-to-fn_virtualfilestats
- https://sqlblog.org/2011/07/08/sql-server-v-next-denali-breaking-change-to-system-databases-database_id-db_id

If you use any of the memory-related DMVs there has been a major overhaul to some of the columns:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlosteam/2012/07/11/memory-manager-surface-area-changes-in-sql-server-2012/

Again, most of these are not caught by the upgrade advisor, so running that tool and not doing any thorough testing could really put you in a bad spot.

And I agree with [Eric's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21781/1186) - you should try to track deprecated events. For completeness, here are three approaches:

- [Profiler](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1370/identifying-deprecated-sql-server-code-with-profiler/)
- [Server-side trace](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2334/identify-deprecated-sql-server-code-with-a-server-side-trace/)
- [Extended Events](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1857/identify-deprecated-sql-server-code-with-extended-events/)

Answer (score 2):

You can also [trace for deprecated calls](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1370/identifying-deprecated-sql-server-code-with-profiler/).